# PHP Read a number from a txt file and make then calculations

Tags: php, file

I have a file which has only one line, with a number from 1 to 40, and I have the following code:

```
$file_line = file('../countersaver.txt');
foreach ($file_line as $line) {
    $line_result = $line;
}

echo $line;
```

I have to calculate the result of `$line - 1` and echo that result.

But when i do:

```
$line = $line - 1;
```

Then it shows `$line - 1` and doesn't actually do the calculation.

Comment: Try `var_dump($line)` first to check what you have in it

Comment: it displays string(5) "20"

Comment: 20 is two characters, so you have extra whitespace in there that is unprintable. It could be the UTF-8 Byte-Order-Mark which is three ascii chars long, but that would have been printed. It might be `\r` or something.

Comment: Not really, php will calculate even with some *noise* in data:) `<?
$line = " \t20\np";
echo $line - 1;` == 19. However `$line = "p\t20\np";
echo $line - 1;` will output -1. It is **very good** practice through to make sure to **operate on proper types**

Answer (score 2):

Your code is weak to changes of the file contents. If someone adds a few blank lines, for example, your code won't work. Try this out instead:

```
$number = trim(file_get_contents('../countersaver.txt'));
echo $number - 1;
```

Comment: same problem it displays 20-1 (20 is the number in the file), maybe i had to convert the string to an integer? but how

Comment: @FlorianWenin PHP is duck typed but you can explicitly cast by using `$int = (int) $string;`

Comment: Even without casting i should be fine `echo "20" - 1;` also `echo "20" - "1";` outputs 19. However if you do `$line = 20;
echo "$line - 1";` this will output `20 - 1`

Comment: @FlorianWenin post the *exact* code you are executing. I agree with PeterM, you are likely using something like `echo "$line - 1"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
$line = $line - 1;
echo $line
```

with

```
$line = ($line -1);
echo $line
```

This will print 19 instead of 20-1.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an approved answer here but for anyone looking at this post, if you have a variable that you want PHP to read as a number you can use intval() function.  Details covered here...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $fin = @fopen("path to file", "r"); 

 if ($fin) { 
    while (!feof($fin)) { 
       $buffer = fgets($fin);         
    } 

    fclose($fin); 
 }
```